# ASP.NET 4.0 on mod-mono?

Tags: mono

What mono packages do I need to install to run ASP.NET 4.0 support?

I thought it was `mono-apache-server4` but [everywhere I look](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/quantal/universe/base/mono-apache-server4), the descriptions say:

> **ASP.NET 1.1** backend for mod_mono Apache module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I had to install to get asp.net mvc working for [widemargin.org](http://widemargin.org)
I recorded what I did [here](https://bitbucket.org/trampster/widemarginwebsite/wiki/Setup%20Website).

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono mono-apache-server4
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

The description on the mono-apache-server4 package is wrong. I have previously brought it to the attention on the #debian-cli guys but so far it hasn't been fixed.